# Jquery 1.11.1 and easing effects

Tags: jquery, easing

I'm using jquery 1.11.0 with the following code to allow page scrolling, by means if jquery.e using [easing 1.3](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

```
$(function() {
$('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Strangely enough this does not work with JQuery 1.11.1

Any ideas why? The changelog did not provide me with any clue.

Comment: not sure about that particular plugin but jQuery animate with easing requires jQueryui, maybe try including it too

Comment: I don't see anywhere that jQueryUI is required, but that's what I have generally used in the past for easing. You can create a custom build to only include easing so your download can be pretty small.